# How to use Timer and SwingWorker in an Eclipse Plugin?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm developing an Eclipse plugin that will contribute to the GUI with a view.

The view is updated with informations from a versioning system when the user selects a folder or a file in the workspace.

In order to avoid collecting data everytime the user goes through the project subfolders and files, I need to wait for 3 seconds in order to be sure that the file or folder is the one of interest.

I'm currently doing this using a Swing Timer.

This is ok for small amount of data, but for large amount of data the GUI blocks, waiting for the timer to execute the update function.

I know for this kind of task I can use SwingWorker but I can't figure out how to delay the task and to restart the delay when needed.

Can anyone give me a solution on how to correctly solve this problem ?

Here is my current code:

```
  public void resetTimerIfNeeded()
    {
        if(timer.isRunning())
            timer.restart();
        else
            timer.start();
    }


    public void timer()
    {
        selectionTimer = new Timer(3000, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                Display.getDefault().syncExec(new Runnable(){
                    @Override
                    public void run()
                    {               
                        updateView();
                        selectionTimer.stop();                  
                    }
                }); 
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Maybe another solution would be to not create a timer, and to improve the performance issue you have, pre-cache all the data you need when the user launch the workbench. That way, when the user select an item, you just have to check whether or not the file was modified since the start, if no : display the cache, if yes : refresh it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Eclipse uses SWT rather than Swing it is best to avoid using Swing code.

You can run code in the UI thread after a delay using `UIJob`, something like:

```
UIJob job = new UIJob("Job title") {
        @Override
        public IStatus runInUIThread(IProgressMonitor monitor) {

            updateView();

            return Status.OK_STATUS;
        }
    };

job.schedule(3000);
```

Alternatively you can use `Display.timerExec`:

```
Display.getDefault().timerExec(3000, new Runnable(){
         @Override
         public void run()
         {               
           updateView();
         }
    });
```

Comment: Using your indication, I need two jobs: an UIJob that updates the viewer and a Job that runs in background and collects the data. Can you tell me how to manage them correctly ?

Comment: If you want to do something in the background just use a normal `Job`, you can update the UI at the end with a `Display.asyncExec`

Comment: If I close the view when Display.asyncExec is running I get a swt widget disposed. How to stop asynExec when I dispose the view ?

Comment: Check the `isDisposed()` method of the control

Answer (score 0):

Schedule it as a Job instead: https://eclipse.org/articles/Article-Concurrency/jobs-api.html . Use a UIJob if the entirety of what it's doing is interacting with the UI. The cancel/schedule and sleep/wakeUp methods will be of interest , see http://help.eclipse.org/luna/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/core/runtime/jobs/Job.html for the JavaDoc.